# What to return if no id found using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

i have a query "details" which is like below

```
query details(
    $id: ID!
) {
    something(id: $id) {
        id
        itemId
        typesId
        itemDetails {
            id
            name
        }
        typesDetails {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

i have defined the types like below

```
type itemDetails {
    id: String,
    name: String,
}

type typesDetails {
    id: String,
    name: String,
}


type something {
    id: ID!
    itemId: ID
    typesId: [ID!]
    itemDetails: itemDetails
    typesDetails: [typesDetails]
}
```

on the resolvers side (graphql) i have to field resolve the itemDetails (with the itemId i recieve from backend). this itemId can be null or can have some string value like example '1'.

and typesDetails with the typesId i receive from backend. typesId can be null or array of ids like example ['1','2',...]

```
const resolvers: Resolvers = {
    something: {
        itemDetails: async(parent, args, { dataSources: { itemsAPI} }) => {
            const itemId = get (parent, 'itemId'); //can be null or string value
            if(itemId) {
                const { data } = await itemsAPI.getItems();
                const item = data.filter((item: any) =>
                    itemId === item.id
                ); //filter the data whose id is equal to itemId
                return {
                    id: item[0].id,
                    name: item[0].name,
                }
            }else { // how to rewrite this else part
                return {}:
            }
        },
        typesDetails: async (parent, args, { dataSources: {assetTypesAPI} }) => {
            const typesId = get(parent, 'typesId');
            if (typesId) {
                const allTypes = await typesAPI.getTypes();
                const res = typesId.map((id: any) => allTypes.find((d) => d.id === id)); //filter 
                //allTypes that match typesId
                const final = res.map(({id, name}: {id:string, name:string}) => ({id,name})); 
                //retreive the id and name fields from res array and put it to final array
                return  final;
            } else { // how to rewrite this else part
                return [{}];
            }
        } 
    }
```

The above code works. but the code looks clumsy in the way i return empty array if no itemId and typesId returned from backend.

how can i handle the case for itemDetails field if itemId is null from backend and typesDetails field if typesId is null from backend.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is more about `graphql` than  it is `react` and `typescript`. You do well to change the tag   of the question for proper matching.

The perfect solution for me would be validating the `itemId` in the case of `itemDetails`. If the value is null, throw an error or return an empty object like you're doing in the else section of the `itemDetails`.

I don't think `itemId` is coming from the backend in the case above, it should be coming from the argument passed to the query `itemDetails`

The same applies to the `typesDetails`.

Using try and catch can help catch any error during the async operations to the API (database).

```js
    const resolvers: Resolvers = {
    something: {
        itemDetails: async(parent, args, { dataSources: { itemsAPI} }) => {
            try {
                  const itemId = get (parent, 'itemId'); //can be null or string value
                if(itemId) {
                    const { data } = await itemsAPI.getItems();
                    const item = data.filter((item: any) =>
                        itemId === item.id
                    ); //filter the data whose id is equal to itemId
                    return {
                        id: item[0].id,
                        name: item[0].name,
                    }
                }else { // how to rewrite this else part
                    return {}:
                }
            } catch(error) {
                throw new Error('something bad happened')
            }
        },
        typesDetails: async (parent, args, { dataSources: {assetTypesAPI} }) => {
            try {
                const typesId = get(parent, 'typesId');
                if (typesId) {
                     const allTypes = await typesAPI.getTypes();
                     const res = typesId.map((id: any) => allTypes.find((d) => d.id === id)); //filter 
                     //allTypes that match typesId
                     const final = res.map(({id, name}: {id:string, name:string}) => ({id,name})); 
                    //retreive the id and name fields from res array and put it to final array
                    return  final;
                } else { // how to rewrite this else part
                    return [{}];
                }

            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error('something happened')
            }

         
        } 
    }
```

Comment: how can i use try and catch in this case. thanks.

Comment: You can wrap the whole async function in a try and catch. I will update my answer.